# Does WLAN work, when USB is turned of in Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: usb, wifi

Raspberry Pi 2 can disable USB with:

```
find /sys/devices/ -name `dmesg -t | grep dwc_otg | grep "DWC OTG Controller" | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d ":" -f1`
echo 0 > /sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/buspower
```

The command also diables the LAN interface.

The Raspberry Pi 3 has WLAN and bluetooth onboard. My questions are:

1. Does the command for the Raspberry Pi 2 work at the Raspberry Pi 3 ?
2. Does WLAN and bluetooth work when USB is disabled ?
3. How high is the power consumption when USB is turned off at the Raspbbery Pi 3 ?

Comment: 1) Have you tried yourself? I can't see why not if it works in the 1 and 2, the 3 isn't that much difference to the 2. 2) Are they USB devices, i.e. do they get listed in the output of `lsusb`? 3) Depends on what the pi is doing at the time, it would be lower by at least the same amount as in the Pi 2.

Comment: Since I do not have a Raspberry Pi 3, I cannot test it myself. I'd like to know the power consumption of the Raspberry Pi 3 when USB is disabled and CPU is idle. On the Raspberry Pi 2 it is nearly 0 watts.

Comment: The wifi+bt combo chip on RPi 3 is running on SDIO, disabling USB should not affect the chip.